# new-timespan error powershell script - date diff

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-2010

```
cls
if((Get-PSSnapin | Where {$_.Name -eq "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"}) -eq $null) {
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell;
}

$sourceWebURL = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
$sourceListName = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
$spSourceWeb = Get-SPWeb $sourceWebURL
$spSourceList = $spSourceWeb.Lists[$sourceListName]
$StartDate=(GET-DATE -format d)

$spSourceItems = $spSourceList.GetItems()

$spSourceItems | ForEach-Object {
$EndDate=$_['Requirement Due Date m/d/y']
$diff=NEW-TIMESPAN –Start $StartDate –End $EndDate
write-host $diff
}
```

Hi There below is the error from my powershell script and below that is the actual powershell script. I am new to powershell - and I know I am doing something obvious and silly - any help would be appreciated.

All its supposed to do is read a column from a sharepoint list that is of the date format and compare it with todays date - if the diff is 0 do something - otherwise do something else - however - I keep getting the error

> 72.00:00:00
>   10052.00:00:00
>   10052.00:00:00
>   10052.00:00:00
>   10052.00:00:00
>   10052.00:00:00
>   8402.00:00:00
>   34.00:00:00
>   8163.00:00:00
>   -94.00:00:00
>   8402.00:00:00
>   388.00:00:00
>   8801.00:00:00
>   10619.00:00:00
>   8886.00:00:00
>   8887.00:00:00
>   415.00:00:00
>   8481.00:00:00
>   New-TimeSpan : Cannot bind parameter 'End' to the target. Exception setting "End": "Object reference not set to an instance of 
>   an object."
>   At line:16 char:42
>   + $diff=NEW-TIMESPAN –Start $StartDate –End <<<<  $EndDate
>       + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (:) [New-TimeSpan], ParameterBindingException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterBindingFailed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewTimeSpanCommand

8481.00:00:00
New-TimeSpan : Cannot bind parameter 'End' to the target. Exception setting "End": "Object reference not set to an instance of 
an object."
At line:16 char:42
+ $diff=NEW-TIMESPAN –Start $StartDate –End <<<<  $EndDate
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (:) [New-TimeSpan], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterBindingFailed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewTimeSpanCommand

8481.00:00:00
302.00:00:00
3589.00:00:00
272.00:00:00
9067.00:00:00
302.00:00:00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So create a sub-expression that actually gets you a `[TimeDate]` object.

```
$diff = (NEW-TIMESPAN –Start $StartDate –End $(Get-Date $_['Requirement Due Date m/d/y']))
```

Comment: I tried replacing your line above with mine I get the same error exactly. Thanks for your help - if you have another suggestion I'd be much obliged.

Comment: If you just do a `Write-Host $_['Requirement Due Date m/d/y']` does it give you an actual date formatted string?

Comment: Yes that does return me the fields in that column - going to come back and verify again. Seems like a really simple script really - but dates have always confused me@!

Comment: How about this, can you add a line above the `$diff=` line that reads `Get-Date $_['Requirement Due Date m/d/y']` and see if it echos back an actual date? Um, now that I think about it, should there be a `.` after `$_` and before `['Requirement Due Date m/d/y']`?

Comment: I tried the above - and again I get mixed output i.e I get some real output that makes sense interspaced error                                i.e ----------------------------------------------------------------This regulatotry filing is not due today
145;#Tara Schultz
8/7/2038 12:00:00 AM
Thursday, July 30, 2043 12:00:00 AM
this regulatotry filing is not due today
145;#Tara Schultz
7/30/2043 12:00:00 AM

Answer (score 0):

sorry I just found out the reason why I have the type error interspersed with the correct output is that some columns in my list do not actually have a required by date - so the date subtraction funciton does not work :) - hence the error between the good caluclated entries - thnx veyr much for all your help - I really appreciate it and my over sight - but you forced me to look in the right place.

Cheerio!